# Kaggle - Image.open OSError: cannot identify image file

Tags: kaggle

The same code works on my local machine, but on Kaggle, I get this.

> OSError: cannot identify image file `'<image path>'`

Here's the code:

```
from PIL import Image

def read_image(path):
    return np.array(Image.open(path))
```

I verified that both use the same versions of PIL, and also made sure that the images have proper permissions.